# Connecting multithreaded task runner with django web application

Tags: django, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I’m developing a web service using django. In addition to the web application, I have a separate module with about 40 functions that take in some parameters, perform some network-bound tasks and return results. These functions (or an entry point function) can be called from django views.

**Here is the flow I’m trying to achieve.**

1. From the web application, users can submit an URL to start the operation.
2. That request should initiate those functions in parallel (with the URL as an argument) in the server (not necessarily all at once)
3. User can do a request from the web application to get a list of completed tasks and results of the ongoing operation.
4. Multiple users can submit URLs to the web application and initiate the operation separately (each user gets a list of 40 results)

Currently I am experimenting with `Thread` and `Queue` classes to achieve this. What I want to know is how can I manage this flow without getting so many threads? How should I maintain the separation between two operation sessions? Is there any way I can in-cooperate the capabilities of django for this?

All I ask is a basic guideline of how things should be organized to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you could call your functions in celery, a distributed task queue module for python. Take a look at the docs for integration with django here: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

There is a module named django- celery-beat of you need to schedule tasks.